# Cross Built Native Compiler Issues: Segfaults in Compiler or Compiled Binary

Tags: android, c, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I'm working on cross-building a native arm android gcc/binutils for my device...specifically to run in KBOX (which creates a standard UNIX filesystem within an Android terminal app using libfakechroot).  I've successfully configured and made several versions of gcc/binutils, but when I transfer them to the device, one of two things happen:

a) Binaries (hello world basically) compiled with the cross-built native compiler throw segmentation faults.
b) Executing any of the cross-built native compiler tools with any options...gcc and bintutils...throws segmentation faults.

I've spent hours trying different configure options pieced together from tons of search results, none of which have worked.  My next plan of attack is to (somehow) figure out how to build Bionic with gcc...but I'm hoping someone will see something I've missed in the details below

**DETAILS**
**Cross-Compile Toolchain:**  GCC 4.7.0 built from Android NDK using the make-standalone-toolchain.sh script, targeting API level 14
**Native Toolchain**: GCC 4.7.0 from the devtoolset repo
**Build System**:  CentOS 6.2
**Latest binutils configure options**

```
sudo sh ../binutils-2.23/configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --host=arm-linux-eabi --
disable-option-checking --enable-ld --enable-languages=c --disable-gold --disable-fortran
--disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libada
--disable-werror --disable-multilib --with-build-time-tools=/project/arm-cc/bin
CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc CFLAGS='-Wall -O -mandroid -mbionic' 
LDFLAGS='-Wl,--entry=main,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -lc -lgcc' 
LIBCFLAGS='-O2 -mandroid -mbionic' LIBCPPFLAGS='-O2 -mandroid -mbionic' LIBCXXFLAGS='-O2 -mandroid -mbionic -fno-implicit-templates' 
LIBS='-lc -lgcc'
```

Leaving out vars for toolchain to conserve space

**Latest GCC configure options**

```
./gcc-4.7/configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux --host=arm-linux-eabi --disable-ld
--with-as=/opt/andv1b/usr/local/arm-linux-eabi/bin/as 
--with-ld=/opt/andv1b/usr/local/arm-linux-eabi/bin/ld 
--enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-shared --enable-languages=c 
--disable-bootstrap -disable-gold --disable-fortran --disable-libssp 
--disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --disable-libada --disable-werror 
--disable-multilib --disable-libgomp --disable-cloog 
--with-build-time-tools=/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin 
CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 
CFLAGS='-Wall -O -mandroid -mbionic' 
LDFLAGS='-Wl,--entry=main,--dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -lc -ldl -lgcc -lm' 
LIBCFLAGS='-O2 -mandroid -mbionic' LIBCPPFLAGS='-O2 -mandroid -mbionic' LIBCXXFLAGS='-O2 -mandroid -mbionic -fno-implicit-templates' LIBS='-lc -ldl -lgcc -lm -lsupc++ -lgnustl_shared'
```

leaving out vars for toolchain to save space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segfaults with cross-native built GCC were due to specifying -Wl,--entry=main.  Not sure what caused the binary segfaults, but I was able to build GCC for android (specifically a NookHD) and compile a simple "hello world" that did not segfault.

The key was to specify the following configure options:
--host=arm-linux-androideabi
instead of:
--host=arm-linux-eabi
for both the binutils and gcc configure. This, in addition to using the -mandroid and -mbionic flags, built GCC to request the correct names of the Android CRT (C runtime) files...aka crtbegin_dynamic.o and crtend_android.o...NOT crt0.o and other glibc (or newlib?) CRT files.

CAVEATS

1. It may be necessary to use the --disable-option-checking option for both the binutils and gcc configure
2. For GCC, --host=arm-linux-androideabi is supported in the top level config.sub, but NOT in the gmp, mpc or mpfr config.sub files (for gmp or mpc the config.sub is configfsf.sub) and it may only have been supported in the top level config.sub because I added it (honestly I forget if it was part of the changes or not).  You have to manually edit the config.sub files for gmp, mpfr and mpc and add the linux-android* target in two places; search for linux-gnu* and place the linux-android* entry directly after it.
3. I disabled all languages except for C, and many of the available options for this build; it's possible this would not work if other languages or options were enabled.
4. Even though the Android NDK documentation states that using --sysroot is optional when working with the standalone toolchain (generated with the make-standalone-toolchain.sh script in the NDK) I had to use --with-sysroot so that the fixincludes would run on the correct headers.